# Assembly passing variables through the stack

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, nasm

So, after dabbling in a bit of assembly for fun, I'm now stuck at calling procedures.

```
...
_start:
    push dword len
    push dword msg

    call print

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

print: ; *char (message), int (len) -> push len, then message
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    pop ecx
    pop edx
    int 80h
    ret
```

When I run this piece of assembly

```
nasm -f elf program.asm && ld -m elf_i386 -o program program.o && ./program
```

It prints out all the contents of the program then seg faults, while if i replace the "call print" with the contents of the print function, it works fine.

Comment: it is because the instruction pop ecx receives the address of `eax SYS_EXIT ` instead of ret instruction, are you aware that call also pushes a value into the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `POP` pops the return addres, the second `POP` pops the address of `msg`. If you don't mess up the `int 80h` call you'll get at least a segmentation fault when the function tries to return.

The relevant values can be found behind the return address, here esp+4 and esp+8. You can access this address directly with `ESP+xx`. When you build more sophisticated procedure you might want to evade to `EBP` but do it with `ESP` for the moment:

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data

    msg db  `Hello world!\n`        ; Backspaces for C-like escape-sequences ("\n")
    len equ $- msg

section .text

    global _start

_start:
    push dword len
    push dword msg

    call print
    ; and the stack?

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

print: ; *char (message), int (len) -> push len, then message
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, [esp+4]
    mov edx, [esp+8]
    int 80h
    ret
```

Comment: When fixing the code, why didn't you clean up the stack after `call print`? I see a comment there, `; and the stack`, but I don't know what that means, and I suspect that the asker won't either.

Comment: @CodyGray: The following SYS_EXIT will also "clean up" the stack. So it doesn't matter whether it is cleaned up or not. I don't know why the OP haven't cleaned up the stack at this point. Maybe it's needed for a purpose not posted here.

Comment: If i pop off the return address and store it, then pop the rest off, can i push the return address back on then return?

Comment: @Jackywathy: Yes, but that's not good style. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The code below is the way you should write it:

```
_start:
    push dword len
    push dword msg
    call print
    add esp, 8 ; equivalent to 2 32-bit POP instructions
               ; (effectively "undoes" the above PUSH instructions
               ;  to restore the stack to its original state)

    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

print: ; *char (message), int (len) -> push len, then message
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, [esp+4]  ; load "msg" from stack using an offset from ESP
    mov edx, [esp+8]  ; load "length" from stack using an offset from ESP
    int 80h
    ret
```

The problem was that the stack did not point to where it should. You have to remember the last-in, first-out nature of the stack, and also consider that the `call` and `ret` instructions affect the stack pointer. When you `call` a function, the return address gets pushed onto the stack, so when you do a `pop` inside of `print`, you're actually popping the return value off the stack, which not only gives you the wrong value, but also messes up your ability to `ret`urn later.

The correct way to retrieve parameters passed to a function on the stack is through an offset from the stack pointer (`ESP`). The first parameter will be found at `ESP + 4` (after the 4-byte return address that is pushed onto the stack by `call`). For additional information, you can look up the STDCALL and CDECL calling conventions that are commonly used by C code.